# Refreshing page - view "freeze" at DIV?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've created a `scrollTo` `function` with `jQuery`, it works fantastically. 
But, as I refresh the page after clicking the arrow that scrolls the view into the other `DIV` (div scrolled into view), it does not return to the top of the page (default view). Instead, it continues to show the `DIV` view.
I don't know if it's my browser or my code, if the code works for you, please tell me!

**HTML**

```
<div class="banner">    
  <div class="arrow-down">
     <div class="arrow">
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.arrow-down {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 10;
  bottom: 5%;
}
.arrow {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  margin-left: -12px;
  margin-top: -12px;
  border-right: 3px solid white;
  border-bottom: 3px solid white;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 20;
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.arrow-down, .arrow {
  position: absolute;
}
.test {
  height: 1200px;
}
```

**JavaScript/ jQuery**

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.arrow').click(function() {
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('.test').offset().top
      }, 1000);
  });
});
```

If I wasn't clear enough, please tell me and I will do my best to answer your confusion.

Comment: I am fairly certain that this is native browser behaviour, do you have a JSFiddle/JSBin to share?

Comment: Yes, but as the code is inside the website, you don't see the effect of the refreshing of the code, if you know what I mean. @Speak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the default standard of Google Chrome saving the history of your position. Whereas it will redirect you to the position you were at, like a bookmark.

This is no issue but just browser functionality, should be worries.

Answer (score 0):

Not jumping back to scrollTop(0) on page refresh is native browser functionality, it is not advised to override this, but if you insist, on page load you can manually set it via:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(this).scrollTop(0);
});
```

This will force the browser to be at scrollTop(0) every time the page is loaded.

Comment: Doesn't work, it just shows the top for 1 second and jumps down to the `DIV`  view.

Comment: @JamesSnowy on Chrome, FF and Safari, latest builds, on several websites, on refresh my scroll position is persistent on save — what browsers/versions are you using?

Comment: OH, that explains why it saves the position! I've just updated Chrome to the latest version.

Comment: @JamesSnowy — What is the URL? Do you have any #'s etc?

Comment: I don't have a URL, it's hosted on my computer. I have several #'s for my links to see if they work.

Comment: Well if you go to: `http://localhost:8080/#my_id` the browser will _always_ take you to the scrollTop for `<div id="my_id">`, thus overriding your JavaScript.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105447/discussion-between-james-snowy-and-speak).